# Not Receiving PayPal IPN With Invoicing API

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

On the introduction of [PayPal Invoicing API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/invoicing/IntroInvoiceAPI/) it states that.

> PayPal sends IPN messages for invoice payments and for invoices
>   cancelled by the buyer.

But I've found this is not the case. IPN for invoice payment, cancel or other operation never get sent from PayPal (I have checked and confirmed it from IPN history page).

**Worth Mentioning**

1. Invoices are being created via Invoicing API *successfully without any warning*.
2. I am working on Sandbox and Creating for Third Party Merchant.
3. I do understand that paypal doesn't send IPN for api operation changes.

The IPN listener is working fine and I have successful implementation for subscription api with IPN.

### Update

Today I tried the whole process with Live PayPal account other than sandbox account and I still not getting any IPN. So, I guess I am doing something wrong or Invoicing API is broken (which I highly doubt).

**Which also makes me wonder about some additional questions:**

1. I (`merchant #1`) has the permission information form `merchant #2` for sending invoice to their behalf.
2. I have setup IPN to my IPN listener URL.
3. `merchant #2` do not have IPN setup to my listener URL.
4. So, when Invoice that I created for `merchant #2`, Do I get IPN?
5. OR, `merchant #2` also needs to setup their IPN url pointing to my listener URL?

Comment: IPN gets sent to the account holder receiving Payments. In this case Merchant 2 is the actual receiver so the IPN will trigger against that acc only. Have you set IPN for merchant 2? Checked that account's IPN log?

Comment: Yes, from `Merchant #2` Profile IPN get sent. But `merchant #1` has the permission from `Merchant #2` and they created the invoice on behalf of `merchant #2`. Shouldn't `Merchant #1` get another IPN too?

Comment: Its not about who is creating on behalf of whom. Its IPN : Instant Payment Notification - triggered to that account only who is receiving the payment.

Answer (score 0):

IPN is get send from the account that receiving payment as @effone mentioned in comment. So, it seems I was confused from paypal documentation.

**Answer:** The IPN url from `merchant #2` will need to setup in order to get notification about invoice payment. `merchant #1` account who sending the invoice behalf of `merchant #2` will not send any IPN as the payment isn't involves `merchant #1`

*Way I see it, this is not a proper solution to create an invoice management system. As if I have 1000's of user they all need to set their IPN url to mine in order to get the application work correctly (aka, setting invoices as paid when they gets paid)*

Answer (score -1):

Your question reads strangely, because you say the IPN is working fine, then in your update, you say you're trying it in your live PayPal account. It sounds like it's working on the Sandbox, but not in production?

If this is the case:

1. Did you activate the IPN under your Production (Live) Paypal account?
2. Do you have the IPN URL for this?
3. Are you seeing the IPN being logged under the Production (Live) PayPal site?
4. If No -> it's been a while since I've worked with this, but there used to be an interface where you could send an IPN test- have you tried that?
5. If Yes -> make a bare bones listener- just a page that logs that it was hit, then add logic to it.

hth

Comment: the problem is the IPN is not sending from my account but only from the account for whom I am creating the Invoice (but it seems this is not how it works). Please read my question and if any confusion comment to clarify before you answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation yet, so I couldn't "comment". I just wanted to try to help you.